# CFDOCUMENT is not putting page number on first page

Tags: coldfusion, cfdocument

I have a page that is pulling data from a table, looping through it, and creating PDF pages with the content.  I've declared a footer for displaying the page number, which works on every page but the very first.  Any ideas what could be going on?  I'm on CF2018, version:  2018,0,10,320417

In the code below, "plusVal" is either 0 or 1 depending on whether the generated report will have a cover page I create later and merge with the PDF.

```
<cfdocument format="pdf" filename="#tempFilepath#\#fileName#_temp.pdf" overwrite="true" bookmark="true" localurl="false"><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Report</title>
    </head>
    <body>  
    <cfoutput query="data"> 
        <cfif len(template.header_logo) AND fileExists("#application.linkMediaRoot#\reports\logo\#template.header_logo#")>
            <cfdocumentitem type="header"><img src="#application.mediaLink#/reports/logo/#template.header_logo#" /></cfdocumentitem>
        </cfif>
        <cfdocumentsection name="#data.page_title#">
            <br><br>
            <div style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; !important;">
                <h1 style="font-size:16pt;">#data.page_title#</h1>
                <p>#page_content#</p>
                <cfif len(data.additional_content)>
                    <p>#data.additional_content#</p>
                </cfif>
            </div>
        </cfdocumentsection>
        <cfdocumentitem type="footer" evalAtPrint="true">
            <span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10pt; !important">Page #cfdocument.currentpagenumber+plusVal# of #cfdocument.totalpagecount+plusVal#</span>
        </cfdocumentitem>
    </cfoutput>
    </body>
    </html>
</cfdocument>
```

Comment: Either move the footer declaration to the top of the document (all pages), or inside the cfdocumentsection tag. [This doc](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-d-e/cfdocumentitem.html) seem to explain the behavior:  *Without cfdocumentsection the [item] applies to the entire document, as follows: If the tag is at the top of the document, it applies to the entire document. If the tag is in the middle of the document, **it applies to the rest of the document.** If the tag is at the end of the document, it has no affect.*

Comment: @SOS, that's more of an answer than a comment.

Comment: @SOS that took care of it!  I moved it inside the cfdocumentsection and it works now.  Thanks!

Comment: @SOS you should write out a proper answer for this question so it can be accepted and others can see the solution.